# Textures from Blender to Unreal/ How to get textures image

Tags: texturing, uv, export, uv-image-editor, unreal-engine

How do i get the textures of my mesh? It might sound stupid, but I'm extreme newbie. When I chose viewport shading: textures or rendered, model looks like I want it to, but when I export it to fbx, the textures doesnt work in Unreal. Can I get like 1 big texture image for this character "printed" as png or such? Or maybe there's other way to get the textures to Unreal?

Comment: You should include the .blend file, so people answering can try it and answer your question.

Comment: I guess you're right, but didn't have access to the file at time of sending the question, but I've figured it out now.